# Install New Version Loses Homescreen Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, homescreen

I am losing my homescreen widget when I update my application version, but the application still thinks it is there and will not let me add new one.  The widget is a weather location and it thinks it still exists, but it is not visible. I have attempted to remove the new permissions to see if it comes from this, but it does not.  Any ideas how I keep my homescreen widget on the screen when updating version?

Edit:  My market version manifest is different than the latest version...for example, my latest contains C2DM permissions whereas my current market version does not.  When I do an update with the same manifest entries...my widget remains intact.  With that being said, is there any way to save state when one changes their manifest structure/includes etc...?